# Should I install Microsoft Office updates for products I don't install?

Tags: windows, microsoft-office, updates

Each time the new Windows updates are released, part of the updates are for Microsoft Office products. However, every time it pushes product updates and fixes for some products I don't have in my PC (e.g. Microsoft Lync, Outlook).

Should I install updates for those products I don't install at all?

Comment: @RsyaStudios Then you are wrong.

Answer (score 4):

The Office suites contain a lot of shared code. If you see an update offered, it may actually update shared components that are used by various Office applications.¹ An update correcting a bug in the Outlook HTML parser will actually be mentioned as being for “Word”, for example. So yes, you do want to install these updates. Certainly there’s no harm in doing so.

My OneNote-only installation is getting Outlook, Lync and InfoPath updates too, so don’t worry, just install them.

---

¹Another possibility is programs that are actually included in your SKU, but not installed currently— these get offered because updates get offered per MSI product code— but seeing what products you have mentioned, this is most likely not the case.

Comment: Kinokijuf's answer is generally good advice, but I would take it a step farther.  Each update has a number you can look up to see what it fixes.  Often, these will be issues you don't have, like foreign language packs you don't use, or network environment issues and your computer is a stand-alone, or a problem interfacing with some hardware you don't have.  I used to install pretty much any update figuring it couldn't hurt.  But I started experiencing problems caused by updates and now exclude those that don't apply.

Comment: Hmm I didn't know that. But if the update does affects shared components, wouldn't the update be named as eg `Update for Microsoft Office 2013` instead of `Update for Microsoft Lync 2013`(the one I don't have) so users aren't confused?

Comment: @fixer1234 Just because *you* don't use something being patched, that doesn't mean it shouldn't be installed, as it *may* be fixing a security hole, that would remain open if unpatched.

Comment: Some updates will not even show up (windows update), if ALL the items they could possibly effect are not in an installed state (not easily accessable).  So I would agree with the answer here, stuff hanging around and not turned off completly or uninstalled completly (parts and pieces) still has to be patched (or shut off) because it still could be utalised for bad.  If you turn on those items, or install them later, you are then likely to see more updates pop up.

Comment: @RowlandShaw - Good point that I forgot to mention.  Security patches are normally labelled as such.  I usually install security patches unless the description makes clear that it is to fix an exploit for a different environment, like a condition that could happen with VPN and I don't use VPN, or a condition that could happen in a network environment and it is a stand-alone computer.  For non-security patches, you need to weigh potential good vs. potential harm.  I was experiencing problems created by patches fixing "problems" I didn't have.