# What is Windows update updating in non-installed components of Microsoft Office

Tags: microsoft-office, windows-update

In my Microsoft Office 2016, I use only word and excel and have shared features, office tools also installed.

I have ticked "give me updates of other Microsoft components also".

I see Windows update updating non-installed components (Access, One Drive, One note, Outlook, PowerPoint, publisher, Visio, Skype) also.

I have selected "not in my pc", and not "run on first use".

1. When those are not even installed, what is it updating?

Are there still certain parts of those non-installed components that it still installs even when I have selected not to install them and will never use them?

Otherwise, if there are some parts used in more more than one component (say word as well Skype, or excel as well as outlook), it should called "ms office update" and not any individual word or excel or Skype or outlook update.

2. Also, if I ever install any of these currently non-installed components, new files of that component will come to my PC. So, does that mean that, at that time, that newly installed component will be again updated for the new files that have come to my box? or is it already updated?

I am on Windows 8.1 and Windows 10.

Part of this is answered in older post [Should I install Microsoft Office updates for products I don't install?](https://superuser.com/questions/838976/should-i-install-microsoft-office-updates-for-products-i-dont-install) that answered very well my other query "how to prevent non-installed components of ms office from getting updated". I learnt that I should allow those to be updated.

Comment: Maybe this article is helpful to you: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/830335/microsoft-update-and-windows-update-offer-updates-for-office-programs

Answer (score 0):

> Are there still certain parts of those non-installed components that
>   it still installs even when I have selected not to install them and
>   will never use them?

You can hide those updates from being installed.  [There is a Microsoft tool for that purpose](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3183922/how-to-temporarily-prevent-a-windows-update-from-reinstalling-in-windo).  Office has shared compodents, you are recieving those updates to those products, due to those shared components that are installed.  You can prevent Windows Update from checking for those updates and just allow Office to do it.

> So, does that mean that, at that time, that newly installed component
>   will be again updated for the new files that have come to my box? or
>   is it already updated?

It entirely depends on the source you use.  If you install from an installer with access to the internet, it will download the current version, and that version will be installed.  If you use an installer that does not check for the updates, you will end up replacing the updates for the the product, and will eventually have to update the product again.

Comment: I have used wushowhide.diagcab and it is very slow, changes many screens. It is not intuitive. Windows Update Minitool is quite quick and works in a single screen. It has been abandoned but still works. Hiding is not a problem in Windows 8.1 as Windows Update has provision for that. This is a problem in Windows 10 which has no user choice for hiding, though WUMT helps there also. Both these methods can hide individual KB numbers, I can't ask them "don't update anything ever about visio as I will never use that".